# I am writing a program in C which searches the number stored in a txt file through a BST but there is mistake which I can't find

Tags: c

First portion of code is storing the integers in ans.txt 
 file through Binary Search Trees.

```
/*code for storin the numbers in a particulr txt file */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct root{
 int val ;
struct root *left ;
struct root *right ;    
};

 void write(struct root *,int);  // to write the numbers in a file 

 struct root *insrt(struct root *r,int val){
 struct root *p,*q;
 int ch,i=0;
 FILE   *fp; 
 if(r==NULL){
    r=(struct root *)malloc(sizeof(struct root ));
        p = r;
        r->val=val;
        r->left=r->right=NULL;  
        i++;
}
 else{
if(val<r->val)
    r->left=insrt(r->left,val);
else if(val>r->val)
    r->right=insrt(r->right,val);
 }
 write(r,i);
 return r;
 }

  void write(struct root *r,int i){
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("texts/bst.txt","w");
  fwrite(r,sizeof(struct root),1,fp);
  fclose(fp);
  }

  void infile(struct root *r){  //storing the address of the root in ans.txt
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("texts/ans.txt","a");
  fprintf(fp,"%d\n",r->val); 
  }

  void show(struct root *r){
  if(r){

    show(r->left);
    printf("%d ",r->val);
    infile(r);
    show(r->right);
    }   
   }

   int main()
   {
       int val,i=0,n;
       char y;
       struct root *r;
       printf("Enter the number:  \n");
       while((y=getchar())!=EOF){
           if(y!=EOF){
               scanf("%d",&val);
               r=insrt(r,val);
               i++;
           }
        }
        show(r);
        return 0;
   }
```

This portion is the search where I'm trying to find the address of the 
   stored number and then from there I can apply the Binary Search Tree 
   method for finding the number but there are some mistakes which
   I coundn't find. Please help me.

```
   /*code for search */

   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>

   struct root{
       int val;
       struct root *left;
       struct root *right;  
    };


    struct root *srch(struct root *r, int a){
        if(r->val>a){
            return srch(r->left,a);
        }
        else if (r->val<a){ 
            return srch(r->right,a);
        }
        else 
        return r;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int num;
        struct root *r,*f;
        r=(struct root *)malloc(sizeof(struct root ));
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("texts/bst.txt","rb");
        fread(r,sizeof(struct root),1,fp);
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Enter the Number:   ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        f=srch(r,num);

        if(f)
            printf("Found");
        else 
            printf("Not Found");
        return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Before looking at the implementation details: you wrote every node to the file `texts/bst.txt` but in the search program you read only the first node in and not the whole tree.

Comment: "some mistakes". Please don't make us guess or start debugging your whole program from scratch. Tell us precisely what symptoms you are getting. Usually by providing the input, expected output and actual output. And also share with us what you have found during your debugging.

Comment: i m getting the result only for root node. if I search the number other than root node it stops running.

Comment: So how can i read the whole tree that's what i m asking

Comment: search returns the address of the found number or null so it is like if(true)

Comment: Code is attempting to save struct as binary (that is OK) with pointer values in them (that is somewhat OK) and trying to read structures (that is not OK as pointers are now irrelevant to current run of code).  Suspicious that the binary file is named `"bst.txt"`.

Comment: so,what should i do

Comment: Only store the number `int val`  in the file.

Comment: yeah But i have a problem with this that when i add new numbers then the numbers would not be in sorted  order.so how to maintain sorting automatically like operating system does when we add a new file to directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problem.
1. `while((y=getchar())!=EOF){` : Discarded one character.
2. `fwrite(r,sizeof(struct root),1,fp);` : Only nodes of the root is stored. Pointer can not be reproduced at the time of reading.
3. `struct root *srch(struct root *r, int a){
   if(r->val>a){` : First, you need to NULL check.

### Examples of changes:

bst.h:

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#define BST_TEXT_FILE "texts/ans.txt"
#define BST_BIN_FILE  "texts/bst.dat"

struct root{
    int val;
    struct root *left;
    struct root *right;
};

#endif
```

---

input_store.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bst.h"

typedef enum ftype { Bin, Text } Ftype;

int fprint_bst(FILE *fp, struct root *r, Ftype type ){
    if(r){
        int count = 0;

        count += fprint_bst(fp, r->left, type);
        if(type == Text)
            fprintf(fp, "%d\n", r->val);//write text
        else
            fwrite(&r->val, sizeof(r->val), 1, fp);write bin
        count += fprint_bst(fp, r->right, type);
        return count + 1;//count elements then it return
    }
    return 0;
}

void fwrite_bst(struct root *r){
    FILE *fp;
    int n;

    fp = fopen(BST_TEXT_FILE, "wt");
    n = fprint_bst(fp, r, Text);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen(BST_BIN_FILE, "wb");
    fwrite(&n, sizeof(n), 1, fp);//store number of elements
    fprint_bst(fp, r, Bin);
    fclose(fp);
}

struct root *insert(struct root *r, int val){
    if(r == NULL){
        r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
        r->val = val;
        r->left = r->right = NULL;
    } else {
        if(val < r->val)
            r->left = insert(r->left, val);
        else if(val > r->val)
            r->right = insert(r->right, val);
    }
    return r;
}

void free_bst(struct root *r){
    if(r){
        free_bst(r->left);
        free_bst(r->right);
        free(r);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int val;
    struct root *r = NULL;

    printf("Enter the number:  \n");

    while(1 == scanf("%d", &val)){
        r = insert(r, val);
    }
    fprint_bst(stdout, r, Text);
    fwrite_bst(r);
    free_bst(r);

    return 0;
}
```

---

search.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bst.h"

struct root *search(struct root *r, int a){
    if(r == NULL)//need NULL check
        return NULL;//and return NULL
    if(r->val > a)
        return search(r->left, a);
    else if(r->val < a)
        return search(r->right,a);
    else
        return r;
}

struct root *new_node(int val){
    struct root *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if(!node){
        fprintf(stderr, "fail malloc\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    node->val = val;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

struct root *create_bst(int n, int data[n]){
    if(n == 0)
        return NULL;
    else if(n == 1)
        return new_node(data[0]);

    int mid = n / 2;//split [left part] mid [right part]
    struct root *r = new_node(data[mid]);
    r->left  = create_bst(mid,  data);
    r->right = create_bst(n - mid -1, data+mid+1);
    return r;
}

struct root *load(void){
    int n;
    FILE *fp = fopen(BST_BIN_FILE, "rb");
    fread(&n, sizeof(n), 1, fp);//read number of elements
    int *data = malloc(n * sizeof(*data));
    fread(data, sizeof(*data), n, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    struct root *r = create_bst(n, data);
    free(data);
    return r;
}

int main(void){
    int num;
    struct root *f, *r = load();//Constitute the tree from the file

    printf("Enter the Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    f = search(r, num);

    if(f)
        puts("Found");
    else 
        puts("Not Found");

    //free_bst(r);//Omitted because it is the same
    return 0;
}
```