# C language - Binary tree with recursive function, printing "node connection"

Tags: c

I am stuck with a part of my code. 
I am supposed to take in all elements that I will have to put in a binary tree and sorting them, and that is working fine, if I take for instance 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, it will print 3 as root, then 1, 2, 4, 5, and then 6, because that is how the recursive function is supposed to work (have to use the one mentioned in the code), and that is correct. 
My problem is that I am not sure how to use pointers and print which ones are "connected". 
For instance something like this would be sufficient:
Node - 3, parents - none, children - 1 and 5
Node - 5, parent - 3, children  - 4 and 6

I am open to all ideas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct _node
{
int data;
struct _node *left;
struct _node *right;

}node;

node* newnode(int a)
{
node *p;

p=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

p->data = a;

printf("%d\n", p->data);

p->left = NULL;
p->right = NULL;

return p;
};

void MakeBalTree(int *x, int left, int right)
{
int middle;

if (left <= right)
{
    middle = (left + right)/2;
    newnode(x[middle]);
}

if(left>right)
    return;

MakeBalTree (x, left, middle-1);
MakeBalTree (x, middle+1, right);
}

void sort(int *x, int count)
{
int i, j, tmp;

for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
    {
        if (x[i] > x[j])
        {
            tmp = x[i];
            x[i] = x[j];
            x[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
}

int main()
{
int i, j;
int count = 0;
int *x = NULL;
char c;

do{
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    count++;

    x = (int*)realloc(x, count * sizeof(int));
    x[count-1]=i;

    printf("Enter more numbers (y/n)? \n");
    scanf(" %c", &c);

    if(c=='y')
        continue;
    if(c=='n')
        sort(x, count);
    else while(c != 'y' && c !='n')
    {
        printf("Wrong character, please enter again:");
        scanf(" %c", &c);
    }
}while(c=='y');

MakeBalTree(x, 0, count-1);

free(x);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: In your `MakeBalTree` function you call `newnode`. But what happens to the node created and returned by `newnode`?

Comment: The idea was to add the value to the node and then return the value. If I remove the value it still works the same. I think I have have to edit the mentioned `newnode`, maybe even add a new function, so you could say that that function is not completed. The part as to how to edit it properly is what's bugging me.
I don't need to calculate the depth and print to tree, forgot to mention that.

Comment: If you need the parent, then you have to provide it in the recursive call to the next level. For example: `printTree(node->left, node);` with `printTree(struct node *tree, struct node *parent)` or similar

Comment: See [create_bst](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39911167/971127)

Comment: `newnode` looks complete to me - it's the rest of the code that needs finishing as there is nowhere in it that even declares a `node *` you could use to store your tree in, let alone any code that would update such a variable

Comment: The newnode function shows you how to connect left and right branches. e.g. p->left=NULL means connected to an empty branch on the left. You say putting the elements in the tree is working fine, but you don't have a reference to the root of the tree, and with nothing connected up it will be hard to show connections! Instead of throwing away the pointers returned by newnode use them to connect up the tree.

Comment: This is only a program that has to print the array and their connections, no nodes have to be added later on, nor searched for that matter.
`MakeBalTree` is the function that is supposed to the value and put it in a node via `newnode(x[middle])`, or is that wrong?

Comment: Your `MakeBalTree` does not actually make up the tree.

Comment: Your description of what MakeBalTree is "supposed" to do is incomplete. Look again at the question put to you by some programmer dude: why are you throwing away the pointer to the node created by new node? What is the point of creating a node and then throwing away the reference to it?

Comment: Maybe to try explain what you mean by "print the array and their connections", it might make the problem more clear. What does "their" refer to in that sentence?

Comment: I will not have to search for let's say number 3, and then print it and its connections, but print all nodes and connections after I create the tree. For instance if I take array 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, it will sort it to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 then it will take the node 3 as root, and then it should print: Node 3 - children 1 and 5, parents none (although If  I print children, parents should not be needed, so I can try without it first). Then it would take 1, print: Node 1 - children 2, Node 2 - children None, Node 5 - Children 4 and 6.
Sorry if my english is bad, not my first language.

Comment: I also meant nodes and their connections, not arrays, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring any other things you have with sorting, etc. The way to print a binary tree would be to traverse the tree printing each node as you move down. The **easiest** way to do this would be using recursion. For example

```
void printTree (node* root, node* parent)
{
    if (parent == NULL) {
        printf("Node - %d, parent - none, children ", root->data);
    } else {
        printf("Node - %d, parent - %d, children ", root->data, parent->data);
    }
    if (root->left != NULL && root->right != NULL) {
        printf("%d and %d\n", root->right->data, root->left->data);
    } else if (root->left == NULL && root->right != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", root->right->data);
    } else if (root->left != NULL && root->right == NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", root->left->data);
    } else {
        printf("none\n");
    }

    if (root->left != NULL)
        printTree(root->left, root);
    if (root->right != NULL)
        printTree(root->right, root);
}

// Calling
printTree(&root, NULL);
```

This is not the best method, it can be optimized itself, and in general it's better to perform an iterative inorder traversal. You can find an example of one [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion/). The gist is:

> 1) Create an empty stack S.
>
> 2) Initialize current node as root
>
> 3) Push the current node to S and set current = current->left until current is NULL
>
> 4) If current is NULL and stack is not empty then
>
> > a) Pop the top item from stack.
> >
> > b) Print the popped item, set current = popped_item->right
> >
> > c) Go to step 3.
>
> 5) If current is NULL and stack is empty then we are done.

Comment: Sadly the linked traversal is not really what I need since it doesn't show the connections between nodes. I will definitely look and try to see how it would fare in my code since I'm not sure what value for the parent I would have to use. And it's a recursion that would be called with a recursion. Ty!

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. What connects are you trying to highlight? The function above should print the tree exactly as your example "Node - 3, parents - none, children - 1 and 5 Node - 5, parent - 3, children - 4 and 6"

Comment: I came up with this in the end without using your code. It's too long as it seems, is it possible to post somehow a big code or would I need to post as multiple comments?

Comment: Actually with my new code and editing your code and implementing it, it works brilliant! Ty so much!